# What is the best way to write and read XML in perl?

Tags: xml, perl, perl-data-structures

I am working with Perl programs that write to an XML file by just using the typical functions open, print, close. The XML files are later digested by a PHP Web application.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#opening file
open FILE, ">derp.xml" or die $!;

#data is created in variables like so...
$first       = '<\?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" \?>';
$openperson  = '<person>\n';
$name        = '<name>Gary</name>\n';
$birthday    = '<brithday>01/10/1999</birthday>\n';
$car         = '<car>minivan</car>\n';
$closeperson = '</person>\n';

#writing variables to file
print FILE $first;
print FILE $openperson;
print FILE $name;
print FILE $birthday;
print FILE $car;
print FILE $closeperson;
close FILE;
```

More or less this is basically how the current system works. I am sure there must be a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create XML from Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154762/how-can-i-create-xml-from-perl).

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, Did not see that question before when searching.

Comment: The community consensus Task::Kensho recommends [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's about these CPAN modules:

- XML::LibXML
- XML::Writer
- XML::Simple

Comment: Emphasis on XML::Simple.  Despite it's name, I've wrangled a lot of XML over the years with that particular module.

Comment: Getting XML::Simple to generate something that a given consumer will actually read can be *very* hard. I recommend XML::Twig, XML::Writer, XML::LibXML

Comment: XML::Simple made my life so much easier compared to my answer below, thank you :P

Comment: The cpan page for XML::Simple says use of the module is discouraged, and that people should use XML::LibXML instead.

Answer (score 1):

I should have searched harder,  [Found the XML::Writer Here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/perlxml/chapter/ch03.html#77002)

From this questions here: [How can I create XML from Perl?‌​](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154762/how-can-i-create-xml-from-perl)

That Sebastian Stumpf brought to my attention,

Syntax is as follows

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use IO;
 my $output = new IO::File(">derp.xml");

 use XML::Writer;
 my $writer = new XML::Writer( OUTPUT => $output );

 $writer->xmlDecl( 'UTF-8' );
 $writer->startTag( 'person' );
 $writer->startTag( 'name' );
 $writer->characters( "Gary" );
 $writer->endTag(  );
 $writer->startTag( 'birthday' );
 $writer->characters( "01/10/1909" );
 $writer->endTag(  );
 $writer->startTag( 'car' );
 $writer->characters( "minivan" );
 $writer->endTag(  );
 $writer->endTag(  );
 $writer->end(  );
```

Produces:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <person>
      <name>Gary</name>
      <birthday>01/10/1909</birthday>
      <car>minivan</car>
  <person>
```

Thank you all who answered

Comment: That one is rather strange. It's not really dynamic. If you want a static structure, you could also consider [Text::Template](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Text-Template-1.45/lib/Text/Template.pm). Regardless, **please make it a habit** to `use strict` and `use warnings`. Please. :)