# Translating malformed HTML to hierarchical XML

Tags: xml, perl

I am currently looking for a way in Perl to write the following output in XML files

- `h1` Is the parent level
- `h2` is the child level of `h1`
- `h3` is a child level of `h2` (or a subchild of `h1`) etc.

#### Example input

```html
<h1>1 Top level heading
Para text 1
Para text 2
<h2>1.1 Sub level heading
Para text 3
Para text 4
<h3>1.1.1 Sub sub level heading
Para text 5
Para text 6
<h2>Sub level heading 2
Para text 7
Para text 8
<h1>Top level heading
Para text 1
Para text 2
```

## Required output

```xml
<h1>
 <label>1</label>
 <title>Top level heading</title>
 <p>Para text 1</p>
 <p>Para text 2</p>
 
 <h2>
  <label>1.1</label>
  <title>Sub level heading</title>
  <p>Para text 3</p>
  <p>Para text 4</p>

  <h3>
    <label>1.1</label>
    <title>Sub sub level heading</title>
    <p>Para text 5</p>
    <p>Para text 6</p>
  </h3>
 </h2>

 <h2>Sub level heading (no number prefix)
  <p>Para text 7</p>
  <p>Para text 8</p>
 </h2>
</h1>

<h1>Top level heading (no number prefix)
<p>Para text 9</p>
<p>Para text 10</p>
</h1>
```

I tried a lot but found no logic to achieve this.

Could someone help me to get started?

#### Update

**@Borodin's** code works well based on the above input snippet, but my actual requirement is as follows:

#### Input.txt

```
<art>Ärticle Title
<smry>1 Summåry
 Summary paragragh 1...
 Summary paragragh 2...
</smry>
<subjg>Subject Group Title
 subject 1; subject 2; subject 3
</subjg>

<h1>1 Top level heading
  Para text 1
  <img gr1.jpg>
  Para text 2

  <h2>1.1 Sub level heading
    Para text 3
    Para text 4
    <img gr2.jpg>

  <h2>1.2 Sub level heading
    Para text 5
    Para text 6

   <h3>1.1.1 Sub sub level heading
     Para text 7
     <fcap>Label 1: Text...
     <grp line1.png>
     Para text 8

   <h3>1.1.2 Sub sub level heading
     Para text 9
     Para text 10
  <h2>Sub level heading
    <fcap>Text only...
    <grp line2.png>
    Para text 11
    Para text 12

<h1>Top level heading
 Para text 13
 Para text 14

  <h2>Sub level heading
    Para text 15
    Para text 16

<blst>Books
 [1] Book name 1...
 [2] Book name 2...
 [3] Book name 3...
</blst>

<art>
...
<art>
...
```

#### Required Output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article>
  <front>
    <title>&#x00C4;rticle Title</title>
    <summary>
      <label>1</label>
      <title>Summ&#x00E5;ry</title>
      <p>Summary paragragh 1...</p>
      <p>Summary paragragh 2...</p>
    </summary>
    <subj-group>
      <title>Subject Group Title</title>
      <sub>subject 1</sub>
      <sub>subject 2</sub>
      <sub>subject 3</sub>
    </subj-group>
  </front>
  <body>
    <h1 id="s1">
      <label>1</label>
      <title>Top level heading</title>
      <p>Para text 1</p>
      <img src="gr1.jpg" id="gr1"/>
      <p>Para text 2</p>
      <h2 id="s1a">
        <label>1.1</label>
        <title>Sub level heading</title>
        <p>Para text 3</p>
        <p>Para text 4</p>
        <img src="gr2.jpg" id="gr2"/>
      </h2>
      <h2 id="s1b">
        <label>1.2</label>
        <title>Sub level heading</title>
        <p>Para text 5</p>
        <p>Para text 6</p>
        <h3 id="s1b1">
          <label>1.1.1</label>
          <title>Sub sub level heading</title>
          <p>Para text 7</p>
          <figure id="grp1">
            <label>Label 1:</label>
            <cap><p>Text...</p></cap>
            <graphic src="line1.png"/>
          </figure>
          <p>Para text 8</p>
        </h3>
        <h3 id="s1b2">
          <label>1.1.2</label>
          <title>Sub sub level heading</title>
          <p>Para text 9</p>
          <p>Para text 10</p>
        </h3>
      </h2>
      <h2 id="s1c">
        <title>Sub level heading 2</title>
        <figure id="grp2">
          <cap><p>Text only...</p></cap>
          <graphic src="line2.png"/>
        </figure>
        <p>Para text 11</p>
        <p>Para text 12</p>
      </h2>
    </h1>
    <h1 id="s2">
      <title>Top level heading</title>
      <p>Para text 13</p>
      <p>Para text 14</p>
      <h2 id="s2a">
        <title>Sub level heading 2</title>
        <p>Para text 15</p>
        <p>Para text 16</p>
      </h2>
    </h1>
  </body>
  <back>
    <booklist>
      <title>Books</title>
      <bookname id="b1"><l>[1]</l><t>Book name 1...</t></bookname>
      <bookname id="b2"><l>[2]</l><t>Book name 2...</t></bookname>
      <bookname id="b3"><l>[3]</l><t>Book name 3...</t></bookname>
    </booklist>
  </back>
</article>
```

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: How do you generate the XML? By direct `print`, using a Template, or using some module like `XML::LibXML`, `XML::Twig` or `XML::Simple` for example? Some code attempts will help to show what you tried and how it does not result in what you expect.

Comment: Is your input HTML? Are there really no closing `</h1` etc. tags? The only way to do this is to code explicitly for the `h1` -> `h2` -> `h3` hierarchy, as there no implication of it in HTML. Your input data should be better formed.

Comment: This is quite difficult to do properly. You need to keep a stack of open header levels and close them in reverse order every time a new header comes along that is superior to the current one. Then all headers must be closed at the end.

Comment: In general use a library, and [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)  is really good; search SO posts for how to write a new XML with it (here is [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934794/4653379)).  If your input indeed comes from (an incomplete) HTML file then it is difficult as @Borodin says; see their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Having said it was quite difficult, I thought the least I could do was to offer a solution!

I've added some comments and I hope it's pretty much self-explanatory

Note that it ignores all HTML tags except for the `<h1>` etc. and I haven't made an attempt to add the blank lines you show as there doesn't seem to be any logic behind them

I'm wondering if this is *really* what you want, as putting multiple paragraphs inside a `<h1>` element is rather odd. Anyway, I hope this helps

---

***Note*** for the inquisitive:

*I am pretty sure that this can be done with just a scalar count of preceding levels. I started off coding that way but ended up using a stack as it helped my thinking, but because `@stack` only ever contains `1..3` etc. I think it must be sufficient to use a scalar that is equivalent to the number of elements in `@stack`, and increment and decrement it in place of `pushing` and `popping` the array*

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

# Read the file and split it on the header tags

my @blocks = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'input.html';
    local $/;
    grep /\S/, split /(<h\d>)/, <$fh>;
};

my @stack;

while ( @blocks ) {

    my $tag  = shift @blocks;
    my $text = shift @blocks;
    my @text = split /\n/, $text;

    s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g for @text;  # Trim text lines

    die unless $tag =~ /h(\d+)/; # Check well-formed tag
    my $level = $1;              # and grab hierarchy level

    # Close all outstanding tags until we reach this level
    while ( @stack and $stack[-1] >= $level ) {
        my $l = $stack[-1];
        print indent($l-1), "</h$l>\n";
        pop @stack;
    }

    # Opening tag, on its own or with label and title if they're there
    if ( $text[0] =~ /^\b[\d.]+\b/ ) {

        print indent($level-1), $tag, "\n";

        my ($label, $title) = split ' ', shift(@text), 2;

        print indent($level), $_, "\n" for
                "<label>$label</label>",
                "<title>$title</title>";
    }
    else {
        print indent($level-1), $tag, shift @text, "\n";
    }

    # Print the remaining text lines as paragraphs                
    print indent($level), $_, "\n" for map { "<p>$_</p>" } @text;

    # Remember that this tag needs closing
    push @stack, $level;
}

# Close all outstanding tags
while ( @stack ) {
    my $l = $stack[-1];
    print indent($l-1), "</h$l>\n";
    shift @stack;
}


sub indent {
    my $n = shift;
    '  ' x $n;
}
```

#### output

```html
<h1>
  <label>1</label>
  <title>Top level heading</title>
  <p>Para text 1</p>
  <p>Para text 2</p>
  <h2>
    <label>1.1</label>
    <title>Sub level heading</title>
    <p>Para text 3</p>
    <p>Para text 4</p>
    <h3>
      <label>1.1.1</label>
      <title>Sub sub level heading</title>
      <p>Para text 5</p>
      <p>Para text 6</p>
    </h3>
  </h2>
  <h2>Sub level heading 2
    <p>Para text 7</p>
    <p>Para text 8</p>
  </h2>
</h1>
<h1>Top level heading
  <p>Para text 1</p>
  <p>Para text 2</p>
</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to print XML on your own, including
indentation handling. I think, a simpler solution is
to use a dedidated module, e.g. *XML::Writer*.

Below you have a reworked version of program proposed
by *Borodin*, using just *XML::Writer*.

```
use strict; use warnings; use autodie; use XML::Writer;

my @stack;
my $wr = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => 'self', DATA_MODE => 1,
    DATA_INDENT => 2, UNSAFE => 1);

sub endTags {
    my $lev = shift;
    while (@stack and $stack[-1] >= $lev) {
        pop(@stack);
        $wr->endTag();
    }
}

my @blocks = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'input.txt';
    local $/;   # Slurp mode
    grep /\S/, split /<(h\d)>/, <$fh>;
};
$wr->startTag('main');
push @stack, 0;         # Treat "main" as 0 level node
while (@blocks) {
    my $tag  = shift @blocks;   # Tag name
    my $text = shift @blocks;   # Content (up to the next <h...>)
    my @text = split /\n/, $text;
    s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g for @text;
    die unless $tag =~ /h(\d)/;
    my $level = $1;
    endTags($level);
    push @stack, $level;
    $wr->startTag($tag);
    if ($text[0] =~ /^\b[\d.]+\b/) {
        my ($label, $title) = split ' ', shift(@text), 2;
        $wr->dataElement(label => $label);
        $wr->dataElement(title => $title);
    } else {
        $wr->characters(shift(@text) . ' (no number prefix)');
    }
    $wr->dataElement('p' => $_) for @text;
}
endTags(0);
my $xml = $wr->end();
print $xml;
```

As you can see, some fragments are identical (no need to reinvent
the wheel), but e.g. closing (ending) of XML tags was moved to
a dedidated function, called twice.

This program is also compliant with requirements concerning
proper XML formatting, namely the XML file must have
a **single** root level node (here I called it *main*).

I had to set *UNSAFE* option in *XML::Writer*, otherwise it complains
about *mixed content* (an element containing both text nodes and child elements).

A quite clever trick is that I used *endTags* function also to end
*main* tag. It was possible, because *XML::Writer* keeps track of tag
names opened by the user, so *endTag* function actually does not require
the name of the tag to be closed.