# How to create a XML by Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm new Perl and Trying to make a xml document.
I came across an article from [How can I create XML from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154762/how-can-i-create-xml-from-perl)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

#
# Create a simple XML document
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'utf-8');

my $root = $doc->createElement('my-root-element');
$root->setAttribute('some-attr'=> 'some-value');

my %elements = (
    color => 'blue',
    metal => 'steel',
);

for my $name (keys %elements) {
    my $element = $doc->createElement($name);
    my $value = $elements{$name};
    $tag->appendTextNode($value);
    $root->appendChild($element);
}

$doc->setDocumentElement($root);
print $doc->toString();
```

I expected that the output as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my-root-element some-attr="some-value">
    <color>blue</color>
    <metal>steel</metal>
</my-root-element>
```

but I got the result as below

```
% perl test2.pl
Global symbol "$tag" requires explicit package name at test2.pl line 18.
Execution of test2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Could you guide me please How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: `$tag->appendTextNode($value);` — You're trying to append a text node to … what? You haven't created `$tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not one of Perl's clearest error messages. But it has improved in recent versions of Perl. Running your code using Perl 5.34.1, I get this, which is far more helpful:

> Global symbol "$tag" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $tag"?)

That would, I hope, enable you to investigate the problem and find the error.

If that doesn't help, then the standard advice when you find a Perl error that you don't understand is to add `use diagnostics` to your code. That would have should you this expanded error:

> (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates
> that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my" or "state"),
> declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say
> which package the global variable is in (using "::").

The "(F)" at the start means it's a fatal error. But the rest of it explains the problem pretty well.

I expect that this error would have enabled you to work out what the problem was.

Comment: Re "*But it has improved in recent versions of Perl.*", The improvement is actually misleading here, since the problem isn't a missing `my $tag;`, but the fact that `$element` should be used instead of `$tag`. It seems to me `Use of undeclared variable "$tag" (did you forget to declare "my $tag"?)` would be much clearer.