# How to add newline for each XML output?

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I'm trying to add newlines to each `<>` line in the XML output of `XML::LibXML`
from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934794/19508169.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'utf-8');

my $root = $doc->createElement('my-root-element');
$root->setAttribute('some-attr'=> 'some-value');

my %elements = (
    color => 'blue',
    metal => 'steel',
);

for my $name (keys %elements) {
    my $tag = $doc->createElement($name);
    my $value = $elements{$name};
    $tag->appendTextNode($value);
    $root->appendChild($tag);
}

$doc->setDocumentElement($root);
print $doc->toString();
```

But, when I tried this code, I got the result without newlines:

```
%> perl test2.pl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my-root-element some-attr="some-value"><color>blue</color><metal>steel</metal></my-root-element>
```

I expected the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my-root-element some-attr="some-value">
    <color>blue</color>
    <metal>steel</metal>
</my-root-element>
```

How to add newlines for each XML output?

If add `" \n"` into `print $doc->toString();` as `print $doc->toString(), " \n";`, it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toString()` method (documented in [XML::LibXML::Document](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Document) has an optional numeric argument that changes how the output is formatted.

> **toString**
>
> ```
>  $docstring = $dom->toString($format);
> ```
>
> *toString* is a DOM
> serializing function, so the DOM Tree is serialized into an XML
> string, ready for output.
>
> IMPORTANT: unlike toString for other nodes, on document nodes this
> function returns the XML as a byte string in the original encoding of
> the document (see the actualEncoding() method)! This means you can
> simply do:
>
> ```
> open my $out_fh, '>', $file;
> print {$out_fh} $doc->toString;
> ```
>
> regardless of the actual encoding of the document. See the section on
> encodings in XML::LibXML for more details.
>
> The optional *$format* parameter sets the indenting of the output. This
> parameter is expected to be an integer value, that specifies that
> indentation should be used. The format parameter can have three
> different values if it is used:
>
> If $format is 0, than the document is dumped as it was originally
> parsed
>
> If $format is 1, libxml2 will add ignorable white spaces, so the nodes
> content is easier to read. Existing text nodes will not be altered
>
> If $format is 2 (or higher), libxml2 will act as $format == 1 but it
> add a leading and a trailing line break to each text node.
>
> libxml2 uses a hard-coded indentation of 2 space characters per
> indentation level. This value can not be altered on run-time.

The value "1" gives the results you want.

```
print $doc->toString(1);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my-root-element some-attr="some-value">
  <metal>steel</metal>
  <color>blue</color>
</my-root-element>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `$doc->toString(1)` instead of `$doc->toString()`.

Arguably, it's not easy to find the correct documentation, because the [cpan page of XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) just contains links to other pages. Still, you can do `print ref $doc`, which prints `XML::LibXML::Document`: you now know that you need to look at [the documentation of XML::LibXML::Document](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod). There, you'll find the doc for the [`toString`](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod#toString):

> `$docstring = $dom->toString($format);`
>
> [...]
>
> If $format is 1, libxml2 will add ignorable white spaces, so the nodes content is easier to read.
>
> [...]